# Media Query to Match Bootstrap -xs, -sm, etc. modifiers?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to write a media query to match the same items that are being shown/hidden using `hidden-xs` or `visible-sm`. What sort of media query can do this? Or how can I conditionally center something (for example) based on those modifiers?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your Bootstrap helper class, *logically* you can use the below media query.

`.hidden-xs` targets elements within 768px and hides it, `.visible-md` will target above 768px and within 992px.

**Visible-sm**

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 992px) {
  .center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

**Hidden-xs**

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .center-block {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```